# MapBasic IDE Switch from Code view to Design view

Tags: mapbasic

I am brand new to mapbasic and I am working on a mapbasic project already developed. The previous developer has left and is not available for questions. I have searched mapbasic documentation and cannot find an answer to my question.

I am using MapBasic IDE beta 1.7

I have an mb file and want to confirm it relates to the windows dialog form I see in MapInfo. I can view the code for the mb file but I want to view the form itself to confirm the which function the text bar is referring to when the user types in information. Is there a method to switch from code view to design view? Or should there be a different file that contains the form design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer in the IDE simply allows you to autogenerate the code based on a visual layout, it isn't capable of reverse engineering the code into a layout. There is an option to save a layout to file in `dialog | *.dlg` format from the IDE so if you have a `*.dlg` file then you should be able to load that. Otherwise, you should be able to rebuild the dialog in the designer based on the code and then you can save it to `.dlg` for future work.